# Hidden input types get's created in ASP.net at RUN time

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, vb.net

For some reason I have noticed that at run time when looking at my source of my ASP.NET page there are tags being created.

```
<input type="hidden" name="_VIEWSTATE" id="_viewstate" value="..lots of text.." />
```

and

```
<input type="hidden" name="_EVENTVALIDATION" id="_EVENTVALIDATION" value="..lots of text.." />
```

1. Why is this and what is it for?
2. How can I make sure that these are not created?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Chances are that you don't want to get rid of either one of them.

_VIEWSTATE hidden field is used to store the encoded value of ASP.NET WebForms [ViewState](http://www.w3schools.com/ASPNET/aspnet_viewstate.asp).  If a normal WebForm-style development (as opposed to MVC) you use ViewState all the time when you do things like `string someText = TextBox1.Text` in your code behind; or when you execute a PostBack and all the textbox, checkbox, dropdown values are preserved without you having to do anything - that's all features of ViewState.  It's very convenient and pretty much a standard practice for ASP.NET WebForms.  You *can* disable ViewState per page using `EnableViewState` property inside the '@Page` directive.  I would assume you don't want to do it, though as you will probably notice a lot of things not working all of a sudden.

_EVENTVALIDATION is part of ASP.NET [Event Validation](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2006/03/20/asp-net-event-validation-and-invalid-callback-or-postback-argument.aspx) scheme - this also can be disabled in the `@Page` directive (I believe the property is `EnableEventValidation`) but I can't imagine why you'd want to do it.

Comment: So you will agree by disabling these will alter the security of the page/site?

Comment: Disabling this would most certainly affect the security of your pages.

Comment: I managed to disable the EventValidation but I cant get rid of the EnableViewState and i have tried EnableViewState="false". Any idea why it is still showing up?

Answer (score 1):

The _EVENTVALIDATION control validates postbacks to reduce the risk of unauthorized postback requests and callbacks. You can disable this by setting

```
<pages enableEventValidation="false">
```

setting in web.config (or setting

EnableEventValidation="false" in @Page directive) but is not recommended!

Comment: Thanks, but how do i disable the ViewsState? I have tried these: ViewStateEncryptionMode="Never" EnableViewState="false" EnableViewStateMac="false" but they dont work...........

Comment: You can't remove view state control completely in the current version of ASP.NET. I've heard that you have better control over view state in .NET 4.0 when this comes out - maybe you will be able to remove this completely in this version?